# Transform one curve into another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebraic-geometry, matlab

I have been working on something for a while now, and I can't really get my head around it. I consider two curves with data points and want to determine the most optimal transform from one to another.

As an example I consider:
[image: Curves]

I have been looking into different shortest path algorithms (Floyd–Warshall, Dijkstra, A*, etc) but these (as far as I understand) consider nodes and their interconnectedness, and not matrices.

The two curves I consider consists of N1/N2 data points in vector forms X1,Y1 and X2,Y2. In MatLAB I use meshgrid to change X1,X2 and Y1,Y2 into matrices that can be used in further calculations. Then I calculate the distance matrix (or landscape) by saying $$D = \sqrt{(X1-X2)^2+(Y1-Y2)^2}$$

I want to use the distance landscape to determine the "shortest path" to transform one curve into another.

[image: Distance landscape]

I am interested in calculating something like the "white line". I have looked at calculating the Frechet distance and using obstacle avoidance, but it does not work as I intend (Frechet distance is a global parameter, and I want locally optimized).

I have included the distance landscape I am considering. Can anyone please enlighten me?

EDIT

I have been looking at the whole "we have a landscape and we want to find the lowest effort-way of getting from A to B", and then I suddenly saw the concept of obtaining the [Minimum Energy Path](http://theory.cm.utexas.edu/vtsttools/references/pdfs/sheppard08_134106.pdf) (MEP) (see figure)

[image: Test]

Does anyone know about this and how it applies to my problem?

Comment: What is the "shortest path" here? The distance metric says how far any two points are, not two lines. Did you want something like $d(\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^1d(\alpha(t),\beta(t))\,dt$? Also, are your lines already parameterized, or are you free to choose the best parameterization for each line?

Comment: If the parameterization is predetermined, the solution is the straight line path homotopy.

Comment: The integral formulation is also probably not what you want; if the parameterization is not predetermined, you can get an arbitrarily small "distance" by using a parameterization that spends most of its "time" near an intersection point, then quickly sweeps over the rest of the line.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Thanks for the comments. The "shortest path" here is the path in the distance landscape that connects the two endpoints (ie 0,0 and N1,N2) - shown by the white line. The white line should just arise from the distance landscape as being the smallest possible sum of steps from start to end point. In general the data I consider is highly fluctuating and is thus not suitable to consider as piecewise straight lines.

Comment: What's bugging me is that I don't see the relationship between the first two lines, and the distance landscape and white line. What makes you think that the white line is optimal? By what measure is it optimal? It seems that you are interested not in a path homotopy (a smooth transformation from line 1 to line 2), but rather a geodesic on the "distance landscape", that is, a minimizer of $S(\alpha)=\int_0^1D(\alpha(t))\, dt$. In that case, you should look up the Euler-Lagrange equations. (In general, a global solution is hard to find, but there are common local properties to expect.)

Comment: Then let me clarify: The two curves consist of multiple points whose pair-wise distance is shown in the distance landscape. The shown white line not at all optimal (its painted by hand here, but it roughly follows the optimal path). It should just start in (0,0) and traverse the entire matrix until it reaches (N1,N2) WITH THE SHORTEST PATH. That is, consider each element in D as been the "weight" we must add to move from one coordinate in the matrix (i,j) to the next (i,j+1). The SHORTEST PATH is then the path that minimizes the sum of all steps.

Comment: The concept of Euler-Lagrange ... can that be used for data points and not functions? Can you provide an example? :-)

Comment: If I recall correctly, it relates the first or second derivative of the solution path to the partial derivatives of the weight function. You can calculate derivatives on a grid of data points via a number of approximations, such as $\partial_xD(x,y)\approx D(x+1,y)-D(x,y)$ (or $\frac12(D(x+1,y)-D(x-1,y))$, or several other options). This turns your problem into a differential equation; then you can try "shooting" different solutions and select the best one.

Comment: So in a sense it describes how a line from A to B will "relax down the hill-sides" due to the distance landscape? This is something I look into. Thanks. But is this really the only way? Intuitively I just had an idea that describing the movement from A to B when you know the cost of each step should be easy to minimize.. Silly me apparently.

Comment: Well, you did say that "general the data I consider is highly fluctuating and is thus not suitable to consider as piecewise straight lines" - I'm giving you numerical solutions. If you treat the distance landscape as piecewise-linear or whatever closed form you have, you may be able to get a closed form solution as well. Assuming I'm not confused, the situation when $D$ is a linear function is known as the brachistochrone problem, and the solution is a cycloid.

Comment: Oh yes, but of course there is a difference between the curves of fluctuating data and the distance landscape. My initial idea was just that **if** you have a $N \times M$ matrix with non-zero elements and you want to travel from a given index $(i,j)$ to another $(k,l)$ **then** you could use some sort of smart algorithm for solving for shortest path (Floyd-Warshall for instance) when the matrix elements describe the travel-cost. This would of course be an iterative process.

Comment: You still have the option to do that; if your curves are piecewise-linear (or piecewise-anything, for that matter), the distance matrix will be piecewise in "cells" that form a matrix. If you average the distance value over each cell, you will have a graph suitable for applying your shortest path methods, which will then be a first approximation to the Euler-Lagrange differential equation approach, which is the "exact" method.

Comment: I just noticed that your description of the path earlier only allows horizontal and vertical steps. Beware that that will very much overestimate the true cost for diagonal movement, because the path length will be as much as $\sqrt2$ times longer that way.

Comment: I could include diagonal movement, so that is not a problem - but thanks for pointing it out! However, (and I'm so sorry) I still fail to see your approach: The "cells" that you talk about are larger than the squares I have drawn, i.e. actual submatrices in D and not just scalar matrix elements? I could just sample the curves using a difference point spacing a thus obtain a "coarse" $D$ matrix. Then in the limit the approach should be possible to apply directly to $D$, right?

Comment: Or we could try to flip the question: Given the two curves (and considering that my data generally fluctuates and are not consisting of line segments) - how would you transform one into the other? How would you determine the optimal transform? Using this Euler-Lagrange technique?

Comment: The fastest approach for general non-line-segment curves would just be to sample the curve at somewhat widely-spaced points, in effect forming a coarse $D$ matrix, as you say. Depending on the speed and accuracy, you may be able to use the actual $D$ matrix, but be aware that this will not be the true solution, even in the limit, due to diagonal effects, so it's not too worthwhile to make the matrix too fine.